# I can't get pg_cron extension to work in latest postgres 16 image

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-cron

The error I get during startup is:

```
waiting for server to start....2024-03-13 03:20:52.400 UTC [57] FATAL:  could not access file "cron": No such file or directory
```

The cron executable is in the path:

```
# which cron
/usr/sbin/cron
```

I did the following steps to setup pg_cron:

Dockerfile has these lines:

```
FROM docker.io/library/postgres
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    cron \
    postgresql-`postgres -V | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F. '{print $1}'`-cron
```

Where that last line becomes `postgresql-16-cron`

A startup script /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0001-pg_cron.sh contains these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh

# We need to append a line to the end of postgresql.conf to load the cron shared library
echo -e "shared_preload_libraries='cron'\ncron.database_name = 'mydb'" >> ${PGDATA}/postgresql.conf

# Dump the postgres.conf file for debugging
cat ${PGDATA}/postgresql.conf

# Execute pg_ctl restart so that postgres reloads the updated config file
pg_ctl restart
```

The dump of postgresql.conf shows that it does have the above lines at the end:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Add settings for extensions here
shared_preload_libraries='cron'
cron.database_name = 'mydb'
```

Anyone have any success with latest postgres 16 with this extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM docker.io/library/postgres

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    cron \
    postgresql-`postgres -V | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F. '{print $1}'`-cron

COPY setup-pg-cron.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD "password"
```

`setup-pg-cron.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOT >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
shared_preload_libraries='pg_cron'
cron.database_name='postgres'
EOT
```

Build and run.

```
docker build -t postgres-cron . && docker run -it postgres-cron
```

You should see at the end of the startup logs:

```
pg_cron scheduler started
```

Comment: I see my issue - I just misspelled the shared_preload_libraries as cron instead of pg_cron. Thanks :)